# Adding an icon for a custom input

Tags: macos, customization, input-source

I have a custom input (.inputplugin) installed already. I'm curious how I can change the icon of the input from just the C in a box to my own icon. The installation was rather finicky so I'd rather not uninstall it, and I'm not really in favor of using Ukelele. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you create an .icns file with the same name as your keyboard and put it in the same location and it will appear instead of the Apple default.  You can get sample .icns files with the Ukelele download.

Comment: Would I have to re-install the input?

Comment: I don't know, give it a try.  Use of the .inputpugin feature is uncommon and there is not much experience to draw upon.

Comment: OK. Rebooting with the .icns file in the same folder and with the same name as my .inputplugin file doesn't change the icon from the default. If all else fails I could try re-installing w/ the .icns file in place.